# ToList() method call throws a syntax error at runtime when ordering a list in a union

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
return await result.Select(student => new MarkSheetsStudentByIdDto
{
    Id = student.RegId,
    FullName = student.FullName,
    AnnualMarkSheets = student.TermOne
    .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
    {
        Rank = x.Rank
        ...
        Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText)
    }).Union(student.TermTwo
    .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
    {
        Rank = x.Rank
        ...
        Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText)
    })).OrderBy(c => c.Rank).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

For the above example code snippet, I am getting the following error at runtime.

```
42601: syntax error at or near \"SELECT\"\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 5680
```

I used **ToList()** method otherwise I am getting the following error.

> Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable' type
> such as 'List'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to
> convert the 'IQueryable' or 'IOrderedEnumerable' into an
> 'IEnumerable'.

Can anyone please guide me on how to address this scenario?

Comment: Problem with `Union` solved?

Comment: Yes, it was solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried the same approach you have shown yesterday for the above case. But it threw me a runtime exception as Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information... I checked all the nullable fields in my DTO and domain but it didn't work.

Comment: Then `MarkSheetDto` should contain fields which are used for joining Term and Comments.

Comment: If it does not work in simplified version, why do you expect working complex query?

Comment: I am sorry. I just updated the code in the question. I am getting all the students' lists. The relation I was given does not contain a relationship between comments and term results. Only I have a student Id to join them. I already included it in the DTO.

Comment: Sorry missed one of your comments. I moved to a complex query since I got the exception at runtime as I mentioned in the third comment in this thread. I thought it is not working due to issues with keys that going to particularly identify a single record. But I used each student's unique Id for the anonymous object in the projected list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load data via `Include` and then do projection on the client-side:

```cs
var rawResult = await result
    .Include(x => x.Comments)
    .Include(x => x.TermOne)
    .Include(x => x.TermTwo)
    .Take(1)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

return rawResult.Select(student => new MarkSheetsStudentByIdDto
{
    Id = student.RegId,
    FullName = student.FullName,
    AnnualMarkSheets = student.TermOne
    .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
    {
        Rank = x.Rank
        ...
        Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText)
    }).Union(student.TermTwo
    .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
    {
        Rank = x.Rank
        ...
        Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText)
    })).OrderBy(c => c.Rank).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Includes can be replaced with Select later when you experienced that not needed data is requested from database.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But it is now throwing Sequence contains no elements exception. In our test data, some of the students may not have term results. And probably a scenario that can be really occurred. I think this is due to rawResult is not an IQueryable furthermore. I am curious why I cannot achieve it through an IQueryable object.

Comment: LINQ translation is very complex task and sometimes we cannot force EF Core to do what we want.  *Sequence contains no elements* means that you have used `First` or something like that in LINQ to Objects query. I do not see problems in your small sample.

Comment: I used Max() for one of the fields in MarkSheetDto. I think it was thrown from there.

Comment: Yes, `Max` can be problem. Check that collection has elements.

Comment: The simplified query you showed me yesterday worked now. It did not work before because a date-time value is defined as not null in our domain but in the schema, it did not have such constraint. It got my issue solved. But I am curious why the code that I have shown in the example failed due to generated query by EF Core being wrong. Is this a limitation in EF core when working with complex queries? As a good practice is it better not to use complex queries when we want to do an operation against it such as ordering or sorting?